# How do I read a fortran binary file in C++ at position of subrecord

Tags: c++, binary

I have a binary file generated by fortran code. This file contains an huge array of doubles, the length is > 2GB. I need to open the file and to read the array. I managed to do this up to the point, where fortran includes the subrecord. The code I use so far is:

```
std::ifstream fin;

fin.open(_fileName.c_str(), std::ifstream::in);

for(int i=0; i<_nnz; i++){

    fin.read( reinterpret_cast<char*>( &tester[i] ),  sizeof(double));

}
```

unfortunately this works up to the position, where the subrecord is included. As far as I know, the position of the subrecords starts at 2147483639 bytes and the width is 2*4 bye long (end-record + start-record). Additionaly the sizeof(double)==8. Therefore I have the records within one double. Is there a way to read the 18 byte information and extract the double out of it? To give a start, I poste my code which is not working.

```
char tmp[16];
char tmp8[8];

fin.read( tmp,  sizeof(char)*16 );

for(int iC=0; iC<7;iC++)
    tmp8[iC]=tmp[iC+8];
tmp8[7]=tmp[15];

tmpStr << tmp8;
std::cout << (double)tmpStr.str()<< std::endl;
```

Comment: Is this a description of your file layout? https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/525311

Comment: I need some clarification:  1) How many bytes in a FORTRAN double?  2) Is the format of a FORTRAN double the same format that C++ uses?

Comment: Thanks for your reply! @Mark: Yes, this is the description of my file layout. @ Thomasy 1) In FORTRAN it is a real*8, so it is 8 byte long. 2)The sizeof(double) in C++ is 8 byte as well.